# Combining lists and performing a check

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an attendee list for an event. Attendees objects are keyed to Profile Objects.
Within the view I'm trying to append 3 lists to make up `attendee_list`.

Models.py

```
class Attendee(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    from_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

view.py

```
verified_attendees = [va.profile for va in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event, verified=True)]
unverified_attendees = [uva.profile for uva in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event, verified=False, from_user=True)
pending_attendees = [pa.profile for pa in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event, from_user=False, verified=False)]
attendee_list = ????
```

What I'd like to accomplish(template):

> {% for attendee in attendees_list %}
>
> ```
> ...
> ```

```
Name            |       Status
--------------------------------------
Jon Doe         |       Pending
Annie Smith     |       Verified!
Abraham Snow    |       Confirm Yes/No?
```

How can I throw these 3 lists into one, and still check which list they belong to (whether in the view or template)? The reason why I want one list is because I will be sorting attendees alphabetically. Thanks for you suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why split in the first place when you could do:

```
attendees = [(a.profile, a.verified, a.from_user)
                 for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
```

and then:

```
{% for attendee, verified, from_user in attendees_list %}
```

You can then control what each says at the template level using `{% if verified %}` or `{% if from_user %}` blocks.

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
attendees = Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)
```

and refer to `attendee.profile`, `attendee.verified`, and `attendee.from_user` directly in the template.

Comment: In addition, if you're going to have a lot of attendees (and even if you don(t), you should consider using `Queryset.select_related` so you don't hit the DB for each one them.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to create a list of tuples: `(<profile>, <status>)`, then you could itertate the first of your lists creating `(profile, 'verified')`, then do the same for the other lists until you have a single list whch you can assign to the attendee_list field and pass to the context?